# What is the difference between a SAX parser and XML Transformer in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom, sax

Can I achieve conversion of XML from one format to another using a SAX parser or a Transformer? If so, then what is the exact difference ?

EDIT:: I mean the transformer I create using SAXTransformerFactory

Comment: Well, one of them is for parsing, the other is for transforming, duh! So with parser you'd need to do the transforming yourself.

Comment: "How is a raven like a writing desk? (c)" I mean, the parser and the transformer are two different things that sometimes can be used to achieve the same goal.

Comment: But what is the difference, could u explain using an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAX parser allows you to *parse* the XML document within Java. It will call you back for every element, character sequence etc. and using this you can construct a object tree representing some/all of the XML, or perform some other function.

Other types of parsers exist. A DOM parser will give you a tree-based object representation of the XML document. THere are pros/cons to each parser type (DOM is typically characterised as more-memory intensive, but providing a complete model of the XML, whereas SAX is lightweight but you're called back by the parser itself and can't navigate any model of the XML)

I'm a little vague wrt. your XML Transformer, but I assume you mean an [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). That's a stylesheet transformation, and operates at a higher level, applying a transformation (stylesheet) to the input XML and giving an output (usually, but not limited to, XML)

EDIT: Following your comment, see [this article](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/445.cfm):

> Finally you probably want to write the xml document to a string or to
>   a file, this can be done with a Transformer object, which come from
>   the transformer factory

Comment: he probably means the [xml transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html)

Comment: I mean the tranformer I can get from SAXTransformerFactory

Comment: @Phoenix - see my amended answer

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

***When to Use SAX***: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/when.html
 and

***When to Use DOM:*** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/when.html

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT4.html

I believe SAX would be for event-based reading/writing of XML and Transformer would be used to manipulate already parsed XML.